# Python Pandas XlsxWriter Center Across Selection

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

**Background Info**

I have a script which works fine for creating a merged header, but I need to center across selection instead of merging. I followed the official documentation, but it's not working. I've tried a large number of possible combinations, some of which I've included below in pictures. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

I wrote the code such that you can just paste it in and run it with the exception of the `xlsFilepath`.  For now, I just hard-coded the text to center across the selection for simplicity but ideally I'm going to change this to the `Title` variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a random dataframe for this example
All_Columns_DF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['Title', 'Col_A' ,'Col_B'])

#Set file path for local machine
xlsFilepath = r'H:\myfile.xlsx'
#Create writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsFilepath, engine='xlsxwriter')

#Write the DF to excel
All_Columns_DF.to_excel(writer, startrow = 1, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
#Extract the header from the DF which I want to Center Across Selection in Row 1
Title_DF = All_Columns_DF[["Title"]]
Title_DF_Unique = Title_DF.drop_duplicates()
Title = Title_DF_Unique.iloc[0]['Title']

#Define WB and WS
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

#Start Formatting Attempt
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_center_across()

''' Hard coding using row,col syntax does not work

worksheet.write(1, 1, 'Center across selection', format)
worksheet.write_blank(1, 2, '', format)
'''

'''Every combination of the below i try does not 
center across the columns. Ive put write_blank above
below, started at col A, B, etc, not thing ive tried
works
'''

worksheet.write_blank("B1:F1", '', format)
worksheet.write("A1", 'Center across selection', format)

writer.save()
```

**Attempts**

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsleJ.png)

[Works but not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31eHu.png)

Lastly, I want to stick with this package, so please do not recommend another package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in the `center_across()` method that I didn't know about. I'll fix it but in the meantime you can use the `set_align()` method to get the same effect:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_centered.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,
            startrow=1,
            sheet_name='Sheet1',
            index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

center_format = workbook.add_format()
center_format.set_align('center_across')


worksheet.write('A1', 'Center across selection', center_format)
worksheet.write('B1', '', center_format)
worksheet.write('C1', '', center_format)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Update: The `set_centered_across()` issue is now fixed in XlsxWriter version 0.8.5.

Comment: hello jmc, i just looked at your profile, and i noticed that you actually created the xlsxwriter package! That's amazing. I'm just curious, how do you go about creating your own python package? Do you have to get python's permission or so through some approval process? Is there any documentation you could point me to for doing something like this?

Comment: See the following on [Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/). It explains all the steps.

Comment: I have the same problem and just downloaded the latest version.